# Variable.SetValue in SSJS not working. It is displaying as blank

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

The snippet below displays [image: Code Snippet]it prints blank. The URL variable is not setting to 'test URL'
I have declared the variable @res_code at the top(not visible in snippet)
Also I have tried using Platform.Variable.SetValue("@res_code",url);
Still it doesn't work

```
%%[var @payload, @ecn , @res_code ,@res_response 
set @payload = '{
         "CustomerConsent":{
         "firstName":"Mark",
         "lastName":"Smith",
         "userId":"m.smith",
         "applicationId":"1212121",
         "termCondVersion":"0.1",
         "Fcc_disclaimerMsg":"Any disclaimer message shown to the user",
         "pageTitle":"CSS-Web Contact Us Page",
         "PEWC":[
            {
               "phoneNumber":"XXX-XXX-XXX2",
               "type":"Home Telephone",
               "startDate" : "2017-07-24 14:14:31.794",
               "endDate" : "",
               "consent":"Y",
               "reason":"CS"
            }
            ]
      }
}' set @ecn = '234567']%%

<script runat=server language="JavaScript" executioncontexttype="Post" executioncontextname=test>

Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var contentType = "application/json";
var payload = '{
         "CustomerConsent":{
         "firstName":"Mark",
         "lastName":"mith",
         "userId":"K.smith",
         "applicationId":"1212121",
         "termCondVersion":"0.1",
         "Fcc_disclaimerMsg":"Any disclaimer message shown to the user",
         "pageTitle":"CSS-Web Contact Us Page",
         "PEWC":[
            {
               "phoneNumber":"XXX-XXX-XXX2",
               "type":"Home Telephone",
               "startDate" : "2017-07-24 14:14:31.794",
               "endDate" : "",
               "consent":"Y",
               "reason":"CS"
            }
            ]
      }
}'

var headerNames = ["frms_tid","frms_appid","frms_source","frms_transactiontimestamp","client_id", "client_secret"];
var headerValues = ["123232","9898989","SFMC","2017-07-24 14:14:31.794","XXXX","YYYY"];
var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);
Variable.SetValue("@res_code",url);
</script>
<Html lang="en">
<Head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
<Body>
<!-- Print URL -->
%%=v(@res_code)=%%
<br>
<br>

</Body>
</Head>
</Html>
```

Comment: I preformed a test of my own and was successful.  Can you provide a non-image based code example? So, I can insure I am not missing anything.

Comment: @DavidDevoy: I have updated the code in my question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works.  I removed the **executioncontexttype** and **executioncontextname** attributes from the script tag.  And I fixed the syntax issue with the **payload** javascript variable.  I assume this should be a JSON object and not a string.

```
%%[var @payload, @ecn , @res_code ,@res_response
set @payload = '{
         "CustomerConsent":{
         "firstName":"Mark",
         "lastName":"Smith",
         "userId":"m.smith",
         "applicationId":"1212121",
         "termCondVersion":"0.1",
         "Fcc_disclaimerMsg":"Any disclaimer message shown to the user",
         "pageTitle":"CSS-Web Contact Us Page",
         "PEWC":[
            {
               "phoneNumber":"XXX-XXX-XXX2",
               "type":"Home Telephone",
               "startDate" : "2017-07-24 14:14:31.794",
               "endDate" : "",
               "consent":"Y",
               "reason":"CS"
            }
            ]
      }
}'
set @ecn = '234567'
]%%

<script runat=server language="JavaScript" executioncontexttype="Post" executioncontextname=test>


Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var contentType = "application/json";

var payload ={
         "CustomerConsent":{
         "firstName":"Mark",
         "lastName":"mith",
         "userId":"K.smith",
         "applicationId":"1212121",
         "termCondVersion":"0.1",
         "Fcc_disclaimerMsg":"Any disclaimer message shown to the user",
         "pageTitle":"CSS-Web Contact Us Page",
         "PEWC":[
            {
               "phoneNumber":"XXX-XXX-XXX2",
               "type":"Home Telephone",
               "startDate" : "2017-07-24 14:14:31.794",
               "endDate" : "",
               "consent":"Y",
               "reason":"CS"
            }
            ]
      }
};
/*
var headerNames = ["frms_tid","frms_appid","frms_source","frms_transactiontimestamp","client_id", "client_secret"];
var headerValues = ["123232","9898989","SFMC","2017-07-24 14:14:31.794","XXXX","YYYY"];
var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);
*/
Variable.SetValue("@res_code",url);
</script>
<Html lang="en">
<Head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
<Body>
<!-- Print URL -->
%%=v(@res_code)=%%
<br>
<br>

</Body>
</Head>
</Html>
```

Comment: one additional question. Now that i am triggering HTTP.Post i am getting the following error:
"
Error Message: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. Line: 1768 Char: 8 responseDetails.StatusCode = Platform.Function.HTTPPost(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues, response)  
Description: An unexpected error occurred during the execution of the page."
Do you know what the security descriptive error is?

Comment: As you may see in the code snippet above..my Header contains the Clientid and secret. Not sure what the security descriptive error is

Comment: You may need to post a new question.  Have you been able to make a successful API call?   When I've done this in the past, it has required 2 call.  First API call to request a Token using the ClientID/ClientSecret.  Second API call will include the returned Token as a parameter.

Comment: Can you please share the example of the 2 calls you are referring to. I am still facing issues with the call @DavidDevoy

Comment: @kunalgidwani you can refer to the online documentation to request a token.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/requestToken.htm